# bookshelf-modelbase - Unexpected token in findOne method

Tags: bookshelf.js

I'm trying bookshelf-modelbase and getting a SyntaxError while running the server:

```
//model.js
var knex = require('knex')(require('../knexfile').development);
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
var ModelBase = require('bookshelf-modelbase')(bookshelf);
//...
```

And the error:

```
/node_modules/bookshelf-modelbase/lib/index.js:77
  return this.findOne({ [this.prototype.idAttribute]: id }, options)
                        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

Has anyone ever had this error?

Comment: Was using version 0.x. After updating it to 4.x problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try Node.js v4 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var param = {}
param[this.prototype.idAttribute]=id
return this.findOne(param, options)
```

Comment: This is implementation would solve the problem for older versions of node using bookshelf-modelbase. @alan-hoffmeister